# MVC design issues in trivial applications

Tags: java, model-view-controller, javafx, properties, model-binding

I'm making a stock simulation 'game', where you can buy and sell stocks, aswell as do yahoo finance api calls and have the stock info displayed in a graph and some labels. I do not want to stray from the MVC principle, and I have a basic outline of how I want my program to look, but in reality it seems to be a bit more complicated.

I have 4 packages: fxml, model, view and controller.

I use FXML to do my GUI aspect of the code, and I load the fxml in a class in the view package. The view class loads in the fxml, has the Labels and the onAction methods (for when a button is pressed)

```
@FXML // 'view' label that gets changed when the model changes
private Label companyLabel;


public StockPanel(StockPanelModel model) {
    this.model = model;
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/stocktab.fxml"));
    loader.setRoot(this);
    loader.setController(this);
    try {
        loader.load();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(StockPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
  companyLabel.textProperty().bind(model.getCompanyName()); // bind the label to the model data
}

@FXML
void searchStock(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    Stock stock = YahooFinance.get(searchField.getText());
    model.setCompanyName(stock.getName()); // update model field
}
```

Is this good design? I'm inclined to say no:

1. I want to keep the view as dumb as possible. This class has too many purposes:

   - read in the FXML (ideally this is what i ONLY want this class to do)
   - bind the label textproperties to the model data properties
   - handle all the actionEvents (when the searchbutton is pressed,...)
2. My model package seems to have no purpose. I could just set the texts of the labels directly, instead of changing the properties. This 'seems' counterproductive.
3. I don't have anything in my controller package at the moment. Ideally I want my view class to only read in FXML, and my controller package to handle actionevents and change the data in the model.

How could I rewrite this?

Comment: Do you envisage `StockPanel` as your view?

Comment: @Michael, I _guess_ this is up for debate, because the actual gui gets made in the fxml, stockpanel just loads it.

Comment: There are many versions and variants of MVC, and it's generally a very loosely-defined pattern, in particular with respect to the relationship between the view and the controller. I would probably regard the `StockPanel` class you show as your controller (it updates the model...) and the FXML file itself as the view (it defines the layout, etc...). (Arguably, this is more of a "passive view" variant of the MVP pattern.) The critical idea, common to all these variants, is to separate the model from the view and controller - this keeps all views of the same data decoupled from each other.

Comment: @James_D You are exactly right. The `StockPanel` class is absolutely the controller here. `setController(this)` should be enough to infer that. The FXML is indeed the view.

Comment: @Michael Well... except of course that the controller has intimate knowledge of the components in the view, and updates those via the binding (instead of the view itself observing the model). That's why I say it's probably more of a MVP presenter than a MVC controller, but that is splitting hairs to some extent.

Comment: Agreed with what you all say, but I'm still left with the design issues. Should i make a seperate controller class and only let this class do fxml loading? and let the controller class do databinding and event handling?

Comment: @user3470438 I would regard the `StockPanel` class you have as the controller/presenter, the FXML as the view, and I think you are good. It sounds like you have a redundant controller class that currently does nothing and that you haven't posted; I would just get rid of that. Otherwise your design is pretty much standard and should work well (by which I mean it will remain reasonably robust if and when you increase the scope of the application).

Comment: @James_D what about the model class? is there a point in having it when i can just update the labels directly?

Comment: MVC is such a widely interpreted architecture/pattern. In my opinion, a good MVC design allows any of the M, V or C to be changed without changing the other two components. However, tight coupling of the View and Controller is common. In your case, I'd just have the View observe changes to the Model and update the fields. The Controller should validate and pass updates to the model, manipulating the View if necessary (e.g. disabling a Button/TextField).

Comment: @user3470438 If you don't have a model class, if you ever added a new view, or separated the current view into two parts, you would have no way of sharing the data between the two controllers without them being tightly coupled to each other. Keeping the data stored in a separate model will allow you much more flexibility.

Comment: @d.j.brown How does the FXML file observe the model though? A MVP approach just seems a better fit for an FXML-based JavaFX application.

Comment: @James_D I'd consider `StockPanel` to be the View, just that it loads and FXML rather than programmatically creating the interface. `StockPanel` should not also be the Controller in my opinion, however its known the Java Swing and FX likes to package them together as a View-Controller due to the difficulty of creating a generic Controller. As long as the Model is separate, everyone should be somewhat happy.

Comment: @d.j.brown Agreed. Separating the model is the important part. The rest is just trade-off between goals of decoupling and simplicity.